# Selenium explicit wait set interval time

Tags: java, selenium, testng

In my automation script i used explicit wait for handling wait time

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(45000));
    
    public WebElement waitVisibility(By by) {
            return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        }
```

Now sometimes I got an error element not found Because some popup messages appear for a very short time.

> error is like (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

**Here my question is how to decrese the pulling time 500 millisecond to 200 millisecond**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see `Selenium` `WebDriverWait` is set by default to poll the DOM every 500 milliseconds. We can override this setting with the use of `pollingEvery` method.
This can be done as following:

```java
public WebElement waitVisibility(By by) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
    wait.pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To configure the *duration in milliseconds to sleep between polls* you can use the following [*constructor*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,java.time.Duration,java.time.Duration)) of [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447):

> public WebDriverWait​(WebDriver driver,
> java.time.Duration timeout,
> java.time.Duration sleep)
>
> Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered
> (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately
> propagate all others. You can add more to the ignore list by calling
> ignoring(exceptions to add).
>
> Parameters:
>
> - driver - The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
> - timeout - The timeout in seconds when an expectation is called
> - sleep - The duration in milliseconds to sleep between polls.

Implementation:

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(45000), Duration.ofMilliSeconds(200));

    public WebElement waitVisibility(By by) {
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
    }
```

Comment: `Duration.ofSeconds`? maybe it should be milliseconds there?

Comment: @Prophet You were right. Updated the answer.

Comment: No, opposite, the first parameter should be in seconds and the second in milliseconds

Comment: @Prophet Thanks for the help. Corrected the line of code.